# codeigniter - get the value of checked checkboxes in the form in other way

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there other way how to get the value of all checked checkboxes in my form and display it on the other view?

**here's my input view**

```
<div class="col-md-6">

      <input type="checkbox" name="sen_id[]" class="Form-label-radio" value="<?php echo $sen['id']; ?>" id="<?php echo $sen['id']; ?>" />
      <input type="checkbox" name="sen_id[]" class="Form-label-radio" value="<?php echo $sen['id']; ?>" id="<?php echo $sen['id']; ?>" />
      <input type="checkbox" name="sen_id[]" class="Form-label-radio" value="<?php echo $sen['id']; ?>" id="<?php echo $sen['id']; ?>" />

</div>
```

**my model**

```
public function view_sen($sen_id){

    $sen_id[] = $this->input->post('sen_id');
        foreach ($sen_id as $id) {
            $this->db->select('*')->from('party_candidates')->where('id', $id);
            $query[] = $this->db->get()->result_array();
        }   
   return $query;  

    }
```

**my controller**

```
public function balot_form(){

     $sen_id[] = $this->input->post('sen_id');
        $view_sen_votes = $this->vote->view_sen($sen_id);       
        $data = array("view_sen_votes" => $view_sen_votes);

        $this->load->view("admin_dashboard/votation_page/balot_form_page", $data);

}
```

**display results view**

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <?php foreach($view_sen_votes as $sen => $id) { ?>
    <div class="row">      
       <div class="form-group">
          <label>Senators</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $sen[$id]; ?>" name="sen_id" />      
       </div>                                        
     </div>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

how to get the value and display it on my result view? thanks, regards..

Comment: `print_r($sen_id)` ans post data

Comment: replace    $sen_id[] = $this->input->post('sen_id'); to  sen_id = $this->input->post('sen_id');

Answer (score 0):

Try like below to check key value.

```
print_r( $view_sen_votes );
```